# why does php doesn't go inside catch block without throwing an exception

Tags: php, exception

I am new to php, i am from java background, i am wondering why php doesn't goes directly when exception occured in try block without throwing that exception manually.
e.g.

```
 <?php
//create function with an exception
function checkNum($number) {
  if($number/0) {
    throw new Exception("Value must be 1 or below");
  }
  return true;
}

//trigger exception in a "try" block
try {
  checkNum(2);
  //If the exception is thrown, this text will not be shown
  echo 'If you see this, the number is 1 or below';
}

//catch exception
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

in above example in if condition the divide by zero exception is occured and then it will directly go to the catch block instead it goes to inside if.why?

Comment: PHP's built-in error checking doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: But my question is ,yes i want to catch it  but i don't want to execute if block if exception is in line where i am checking for division , if i remove the throw inside if then it will not goes to catch block instead it will execute next code , still having exception in if statement.

Comment: It's not executing the `if()` block. `$number/0` returns `false` because of the division by 0, so it doesn't execute the `if()`. Then the function returns `true`, and it prints the `If you see this` message.

Comment: Why are you dividing the number by 0 to tell if it's 1 or below?

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted doesn't do what you say it does.

When you execute:

```
if ($number/0)
```

the division by zero prints a warning, and then returns `false`. Since the value is not truthy, it doesn't go into the `if` block, so it doesn't execute the `throw` statement. The function then returns `true`. Since the exception wasn't thrown, the statement after the call to `checkNum(2)` is executed, so it prints the message.

When I run your code, I get the output:

```
Warning: Division by zero in scriptname.php on line 5
If you see this, the number is 1 or below
```

PHP doesn't use exceptions for its built-in error checks. It simply displays or logs the error, and if it's a fatal error it stops the script.

This has been changed in PHP 7, though. It now reports errors by throwing an exception of type `Error`. This isn't a subclass of `Exception`, so it won't be caught if you use `catch (Exception $e)`, you'll need to use `catch (Error $e)`. See [Errors in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php). So in PHP 7 you could write:

```
<?php
//create function with an exception
function checkNum($number) {
  if($number/0) {
    throw new Exception("Value must be 1 or below");
  }
  return true;
}

//trigger exception in a "try" block
try {
  checkNum(2);
  //If the exception is thrown, this text will not be shown
  echo 'If you see this, the number is 1 or below';
}

//catch exception
catch(Error $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thank's @Barmar, you save my day. since two days of bug...  no solution....Thank's